# DNS Resource Record Type Field (MB, MG, MR)

Tags: dns, resources, record, rr

What is usage of MB, MG, MR types in a Resource Record?

Some information in [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758321%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), but I can't understand their usage in real world!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that those records are obsolete. 
They were trying to replace some SMTP commands like VRFY and EXPN.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [IANA DNS parameters list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xhtml) they were `EXPERIMENTAL` RR types proposed (before the DNS properly existed) in [RFC 883](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc883) and specified in [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035).

AFAIK, they've never seen any significant real-world deployment.